# Cannot initialize effect engine

Tags: android, kotlin, android-audio-record

При вызове метода setEqualizerData(), а именно при инициализации myEq = Equalizer(0, musicPlayingId) возникает ошибка:
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize effect engine for type: 0bed4300-ddd6-11db-8f34-0002a5d5c51b Error: -3

```
private fun setEqualizerData() {
    myEq = Equalizer(0, musicPlayingId) //Error
    myEq!!.enabled = true
    setBoost(sharedPreferences.getFloat(LOUDER_LEVEL, 1f))
    myEq!!.setBandLevel(
        0,
        sharedPreferences.getInt(BAND_1_LEVEL, 1500).toShort()
    )
    myEq!!.setBandLevel(
        1,
        sharedPreferences.getInt(BAND_2_LEVEL, 1500).toShort()
    )
    myEq!!.setBandLevel(
        2,
        sharedPreferences.getInt(BAND_3_LEVEL, 1500).toShort()
    )
    myEq!!.setBandLevel(
        3,
        sharedPreferences.getInt(BAND_4_LEVEL, 1500).toShort()
    )
    myEq!!.setBandLevel(
        4,
        sharedPreferences.getInt(BAND_5_LEVEL, 1500).toShort()
    )
    mBassBoost = BassBoost(0, musicPlayingId)
    mBassBoost!!.enabled = true
    setBassBoost()
    virtualizer = Virtualizer(0, musicPlayingId)
    virtualizer!!.enabled = true
    setVirtualizer()
    loudness = LoudnessEnhancer(musicPlayingId)
}
```

стектрейс:

```
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize effect engine for type: 0bed4300-ddd6-11db-8f34-0002a5d5c51b Error: -3
   at android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect.<init>(AudioEffect.java:468)
   at android.media.audiofx.Equalizer.<init>(Equalizer.java:139)
   at example.androidvolumelouder.presentation.ui.activities.MainActivity.setEqualizerData(MainActivity.kt:343)
   at example.androidvolumelouder.presentation.ui.activities.MainActivity.setDataToView(MainActivity.kt:529)
   at example.androidvolumelouder.presentation.ui.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:147)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3310)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3484)
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2068)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7551)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
```

Помогите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Внес изменения.